# KML layer using leaflet-omnivore not showing in Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, kml, mapbox

I searched for this topic but could not find any other instances. I am attempting to add KML layers using `leaflet-omnivore` to my Mapbox map, but each time the map loads, the basemap works but the KML layers (which should be in the same extent) do not load. The HTML document and the KML layers are hosted on the same domain. I am new to using `leaflet-omnivore`, and wondered if I am doing something wrong? The coordinate system for the KML also is WGS84, so I don't see how that could be the issue, either. I've basically copy and pasted the code from the example and am running that, other than substituting my own URL for the example, as well as adjusting the map basemap, extent, and key.

Any help or insight appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>KML Data</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.3/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.3/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'deleted for post';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map','mapbox.light').setView([41.5, -72.67], 9);

// omnivore will AJAX-request this file behind the scenes and parse it:
// note that there are considerations:
// - The file must either be on the same domain as the page that requests it,
//   or both the server it is requested from and the user's browser must
//   support CORS.

// Internally this uses the toGeoJSON library to decode the KML file
// into GeoJSON
var runLayer = omnivore.kml('http://magic.lib.uconn.edu/magic_2/vector/apindex_37800_0000_1934_s12_FAS_1_shp_wgs84.kml')
    .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How big is your KML file? How long does it take to download it? Would your AJAX request (inside omnivore) time out before it finishes downloading?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The file is 14.6 MB and takes about 5-6 seconds to download (where I am it's about 94 mbps). I unfortunately don't have a lot of experience with AJAX so am unsure completely what would be happening behind the scenes so to speak. I don't feel like that file size is particularly big.

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain issue: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://magic.lib.uconn.edu/magic_2/vector/apindex_37800_0000_1934_s12_FAS_1_shp_wgs84.kml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` (unless that is the same domain your page is on)

Comment: @Kate I know this is a very old question, still need to ask did you find the solution for this issue.

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy I ended up using the Google Maps API instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your icons aren't defined correctly.  It looks like you might have not converted the URL when you decompressed the KMZ.

```
<Style id="IconStyle00">
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.25</scale>
        <Icon>
            <href>df080276-b1b3-4280-bf72-a57bb8c4960e.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
        <color>00000000</color>
        <scale>0</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
        <outline>0</outline>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

If I add a url to an icon, [I see them show up on the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20151105_leafletB.html), but it does take a while to render.

Comment: Wow how many points (markers) are there in this KML??? O.o It is like the whole State is full! @Kate if you have more than 50 markers on screen, you'd better use [Leaflet.markercluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) ([Mapbox version](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/#leaflet-markercluster)) The rendering process (trying to show all those markers on screen) is very probably what slows down your map.

Answer (score 0):

This KML file is 14mb - loading this with AJAX into a Leaflet map isn't the best approach, because it'll take a long time to load and be slow once it's on the map. Your best bet would be to bring this data into a tool like TileMill or CartoDB to generate tiles from it, and put those on a map.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Part of the reason I had switched to Leaflet/Mapbox from Google Maps is because the UI was a lot prettier with more options, but unfortunately this combo can't handle .kmz files, which is what all of my files are (over 50). I planned to decompress them all to use it, but I may have to go back to GMaps which can natively handle KMZ I guess if this is the case. Otherwise a lot of work to go through even more conversion efforts. I will look into it though. Doesn't explain why it didn't load at all though? Just too slow?

Comment: I think it was loading, there just wasn't anything to see (no icons).